# Nginx reverse proxy redirect properly, but requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 virtual machines on GCP who are in the same VPC. One (call it serverA) has external ip address and second (call it serverB) has only internal ip address.
On serverB I have `x-wiki` app running on `8080 port`. Access to this app is via ssh-tunnel. I want to have access to this app via serverA network interface, so I've run nginx server on docker and it looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /tmp/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

and `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
events{}
http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.0.3:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

while hitting in browser at `serverA-EXTERNAL-IP-ADDRESS:8080`, I got proper endpoint for `x-wiki` app (`/bin/view/Main/`), but instead of content I got 404 error, that `The requested URL was not found on this server.` Could somebody help my to find solution or give any advice what I did wrong or what I'm missing?

Edit:

While running `curl 172.16.0.3:8080/bin/view/Main` on serverA I get a bunch of html which is a main page of x-wiki. While running `curl serverA-EXTERNAL-IP:8080/bin/view/Main` I got the same output. While running `ping 172.16.0.3` from serverA I get:

```
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.71 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.261 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.279 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.3: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.287 ms
```

About firewalls: on my gcp I checked boxes to allow trafic via HTTP and HTTPS. I also added rules for all instances and defined ports (5050, 8080, etc)

Edit2:

This is my configuration of x-wiki, postgres and pgadmin which run on serverB.

```
version: '2'
networks:
  bridge:
    driver: bridge
services:
  web:
    image: "xwiki:lts-postgres-tomcat"
    container_name: xwiki-postgres-tomcat-web
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - DB_HOST=xwiki-postgres-db
    volumes:
      - /tmp/xwiki:/usr/local/xwiki
    networks:
      - bridge
  db:
    image: "postgres:13"
    container_name: xwiki-postgres-db
    volumes:
      - /tmp/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=xwiki
      - POSTGRES_DB=xwiki
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="--encoding=UTF8"
    networks:
      - bridge
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: email
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - bridge
volumes:
  postgres-data: {}
  xwiki-data: {}
```

Comment: What troubleshooting have you performed? Have you tried telnet to from serverA the IP and port of serverB? Have you checked your firewall? and SSH permissions?

Comment: Simplify your question. Show the configuration for both systems. Then show the tests that you made. For example, on Server A, run this command to verify that Aerver A can talk to server b: **curl -v http://172.16.0.3:8080**. If that does not work, fix that problem. If it does work, repeat a similar command from your desktop to Server A. Put the command and output in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added edit

Comment: Some tips: VM to VM using internal IP address is allowed on all ports via a precreated VPC firewall rule. The network tags HTTP (means port 80) and HTTP (means port 443) do not open any port using HTTP or HTTPS, just port 80 and 443.

Comment: Since both curl commands work, what is the problem?

Comment: @JohnHanley that's weird, bacause it works now. But while entering in web browser my `serverA external-ip:8080`,  my urls changes to: `http://serverA-external-ip/bin/view/Main/`. At this endpoint I got 404, but when I edit this address and add 8080 port I got a proper website

Comment: **serverA-external-ip** and **serverA-external-ip:8080** are two different ports. The first is port 80, the second is port 8080. Something redirected port 80. That configuration is not in your question. Port 80 might be something running on the Docker host.

Comment: @JohnHanley I added my docker-compose from server b

Comment: @Frendom redirection from IP address:port to URL might have to do with your DNS records. Also, you should check your server's hostfile for both serverA and serverB, if assigned IP, URL and port are correct. Another firewall you should check is your OS firewall where your app is hosted, OS firewall set up by default, only have basic service and ports added (e.g. ssh, http, https), some of the OS, but sometime you need to add service you want and the port for that service.